# How to restricts firebase storage access with my own authentication service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage in my app, And i am using my own user name and password authentication service, I have changed the rules to public so that i can upload and download data, but now i it gives me this warning

> Your security rules are set to public. Anyone can read or write to
>   your storage bucket

How can i protect app data without using any firebase sign-in or authentication methods ??

Comment: Well if you don't have any authentication I don't see why it would be necessary to protect your app data? Since, I assume, you want everyone to be able to access the data.

Comment: my app is authenticated throw my own user name and password service but app storage is not protected as there is no authentication from firebase so i am looking for a way to secure the storage data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using your own service to authenticate users I can think of two options, both involving the admin SDK.

**Option 1: Creating a custom token**

Assuming you're authenticating users via a service running on your own server, you could slightly edit that system to include custom tokens by using the Firebase Admin SDK. Basically, if the details provided by the user match the details your service expected you can return a custom token that firebase can use to authenticate users. Then you can set Firebase security rules as you normally would. This is what I would recommend doing.

[Create custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

**Option 2: Restrict access completely and request/upload data via your server**

You can set your your security rules to `false` to restrict access to everyone. The Admin SDK should disregard these rules since it's an administration instance. You could then have your users upload files (or download requests) to your server. Your server would then use the Admin SDK to request the files from Firebase and send them back to the user.

[Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: what i get from solution 1 is that Firebase Admin SDKi will generate custom token for any user that register to my service and i should check this token every time the user try to login, am i true??

Comment: Not exactly. To explain it very simply. Every time an user tries to log in on your application, you send their username and password to your authentication service, and if that username/password combination exists on your server you create a token and send that to the user. The token basically says to firebase 'this person was validated on our backend and should be logged in'. That token will allow the user to authenticate with Firebase. But it creates a new token every time a user tries to log in, not when registering. It's not like every user has a set token that can be reused.

Comment: Ok i got it but the token will be generated by my service or by Firebase Admin SDK??, And will this approach affect firebase notification implementaion ??

Comment: Don't think it will affect Firebase notifications. And the token is generated by the Firebase Admin SDK through the `auth().createCustomToken(uid)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Give Read and Write permission only for the authorised users as below,

```
"rules": {
  ".read":  "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
 }
 }
```

Now you wont get any warnings.

Comment: but then users will not be able to upload or download any data as there no authentication

Comment: only the authorised user can able to access the realtime database or the firebase storage

Comment: only when the authorization done, you will get the Database reference.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase rules are for both read and write

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

you can make a variable read as true so that others can read the data but they can write into your data. hence your data is safe .
Hope you got it

Comment: the rules that you putted are for the database and the question is about storage